# java - Showing Unity WebPlayer Content

Tags: java, swing, javafx, unity-web-player

I was wondering if there is any way to show Unity Web Player content from a link in JavaFX or  Swing? I looked at JxBrowser but it uses Chromium 55 in which Unity WebPlayer is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you're stuck to JxBrowser. Swing is very very limited in this area.

If JxBrowser is not supported, then your only other alternatives are SWT...

Have you tried the [JavaFX  WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html)?